# I'm getting more rows than the original table when i'm using the left joins

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT a.COMPID
    ,a.A_COMPID
    ,a.A_CLIENTID
    ,a.A_CUSTNAME
    ,b.CLIENTID
    ,b.CLIENTNAME
FROM A_CUSTOMERS AS a
LEFT JOIN CLIENTS AS b ON b.COMPID = a.COMPID
    AND b.A_CLIENTID = a.A_CLIENTID
WHERE a.COMPID = 1000
```

Comment: That happens when the table you are joining to has a 1:many relationship with your table. I assume you have more than one client per customer, right (or you have more than one record per `clientid` in your `Clients` table)? How would you like those to be displayed when there is more than one? Please add some sample data and your desired results and we can help out more.

Comment: Slight detour, but relevant since you seem likely to be relatively new to sql. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: maybe you should try joining to `CLIENTS` on `b.CLIENTID = a.A_CLIENTID`

Comment: Please provide some context to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask has a section on introducing the problem before posting any code